# Query for only one client entry a day

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have table with a definition like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Contact]
(
    ClientNumber [numeric] (20, 0) NULL,
    ContactDate [Date] NULL,
    Name [text] NULL,
    AdditionalInformation [text] NULL
)
```

This table is filled with information for a single month. Each client may have multiple entries for a single day. Meaning there might be entries like this:

```
42  2015-12-09  Felix       called today
42  2015-12-09  Fexclicx    ...
```

My goal is to get all client results from the table with the condition that there should be only one entry a day per client number. I do not care which of the (here) two entries is displayed, so something like `top 1`.

So far I tried to achive this with a distinct:

```
select distinct ClientNumber, ContactDate, * from Contact
```

Unfortunately this does not limit the results to show a client entry for a specific date only once. They still all do appear.

How could I achive getting all entries but only one entry for one client per day?

Comment: You seem to be asking the table for all records which have a column with unique information, and that is what you are getting (you are asking for "distinct" across all columns). If you limit yourself to the clientnumber and contractdate you will get what I think you are asking for

Comment: this could be very easy if you had an ID on the Contact Table, check my answer.

Comment: @StianYttervik Is it unclear what I am asking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you edit your table, so it has an ID column ( you could set it as primary key). If you do so, you can use the query I've posted.

I don't know how you will get the desire information with group by, as you can't aggregate text columns.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[#Contact]
(
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
    ClientNumber [numeric] (20, 0) NULL,
    ContactDate [Date] NULL,
    Name [text] NULL,
    AdditionalInformation [text] NULL
)


declare @Date datetime
set @Date = GETDATE()
INSERT INTO #Contact VALUES (1,@Date,'First Client','Info 1')
GO
declare @Date datetime
set @Date = GETDATE()
set @Date = DATEADD(DAY,RAND()*100,@Date)
INSERT INTO #Contact VALUES (1,@Date,'First Client','Info 2')
GO
declare @Date datetime
set @Date = GETDATE()
set @Date = DATEADD(DAY,RAND()*100,@Date)
print @Date
INSERT INTO #Contact VALUES (2,@Date,'2nd Client','Info 1')
GO
declare @Date datetime
set @Date = GETDATE()
set @Date = DATEADD(DAY,RAND()*100,@Date)
INSERT INTO #Contact VALUES (2,@Date,'2nd Client','Info 2')
GO
declare @Date datetime
set @Date = GETDATE()
set @Date = DATEADD(DAY,RAND()*100,@Date)
INSERT INTO #Contact VALUES (2,@Date,'2nd Client','Info 3')
GO
declare @Date datetime
set @Date = GETDATE()
set @Date = DATEADD(DAY,RAND()*100,@Date)
INSERT INTO #Contact VALUES (3,@Date,'3rd Client','Info 1')







SELECT * FROM #Contact  c1 join (
      SELECT ClientNumber, MAX(ID) MaxID
      FROM #Contact
      GROUP BY ClientNumber ) c2 on  c1.ClientNumber = c2.ClientNumber and c1.ID = c2.MaxID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use grouping functions, like this:

```
SELCET ClientNumber, ContactDate, Name
FROM Contact
GROUP BY ContactDate, Name
```

Comment: That will throw an error since all columns must either be in the group by or in an aggregated state.